# Use Android device as external monitor from a Linux box **in a fluid way**

Tags: usb, external-display

My need is to setup a VR headset with a smartphone inside, displaying the game that runs on a computer. I've done my homework and I already know about all the VNC-based solutions, but here the latency and fluidity are paramount.

I've setup a windows 10 box with the spacedesk software (a server on the pc, a client on the smartphone) and **it works flawlessly** when I connect the usb cable, setup the phone as connection share and use this direct IP address. I haven't fully tested it but it seems perfect for my need, so I know the hardware is not a limitation.

I want to do **the same on a linux box** (mint 20) so I tested variations of [this idea](https://sangams.com.np/using-android-pc-as-a-second-monitor-in-linux/), using x11vnc. It works but it's not usable for a game (it might be for office work). I get about 1 FPS, many glitches when the image changes suddenly, I cannot imagine to play this way. If I reduce the color space drastically it's slightly better (not even good) but of course ugly.

So my question : are there options I can set to make it fluid ? Is there another protocol better suited ? I don't need the taking control capability, a simple video stream fits my needs, that's an idea I havent explored. I don't mind having a cable attached, so maybe there's a way using adb, I know the reverse is possible but I didn't find a solution to my need.

Comment: I am sorry but that VNC does not work well does not surprise me. VNC is old and the protocols are usually not performance optimized. I would suggest to use a different approach: Take the phone as video-streaming client. If you use a codec that can be decoded by the phone in hardware the performance should be outstanding compared to VNC. And the PC could do the video encoding using it's GPU. That should provide a minimal latency.

Comment: I would search on "desktop streaming" and "WebRTC" for possible solutions.